Enhanced switch for non-public classes
Occasionally a 3rd party library contains APIs that return non-public classes which you cannot reference directly. One such example is org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord.get() which can sometimes return a java.nio.HeapByteBuffer object. If I wanted to switch over that class like so I will get a compile error:
Object recordValue = genericRecord.get(someField);
switch (actualValue) {
   case String avroString -> {
      // do logic
   }
   case HeapByteBuffer avroBuffer -> {
      // do logic
   }
   default -> log.warn("Unknown type");
}

If instead I try to use an extending class, the code will compile but will log the warning message "Unknown type":
Object recordValue = genericRecord.get(someField);
switch (actualValue) {
   case String avroString -> {
      // do logic
   }
   case ByteBuffer avroBuffer -> {
      // do logic
   }
   default -> log.warn("Unknown type");
}

How can I use an enhanced switch for a private class?

Class HeapByteBuffer seems to be generated from a template and doesn't even exist as a source file in the JDK source.  You can't effectively refer to anything inside it except as a ByteBuffer, and your code can break with any JDK update.  What exactly do intend to do where you have // do logic that requires HeapByteBuffer?  If all you want to do is avoid a warning, what warning do you see?

@ThomasKläger I meant that the the log.warn() line is called. I.e. It is passing over the ByteBuffer case.

@JimGarrison I don't understand what you mean when you say HeapByteBuffer is generated from a template. Its part of the JDK and been that way for a long time. Nowadays in JDK21+ world it is even explicitly permitted in a sealed hierarchy.  I dont think a JDK update will get rid of it..... Also, I don't really care that it is a HeapByteBuffer. Thats just what avro gives me. I'm perfectly happy treating it as a ByteBuffer if thats all I have. If you have an answer on how to use a HeapByteBuffer or a better way around this problem than I've already posted I'd love to hear it!

Well, I have the JDK20 Javadoc, and it does not contain HeapByteBuffer.  Where do you see the Javadoc for that class?

The case ByteBuffer b is effectively just an instanceof check. So, if you're using java.nio.ByteBuffer and the object is a java.nio.HeapByteBuffer, then that case will be executed, not the default one. If your code is not working that way, then I suggest you [edit] your question to provide a [mre].

"I don't understand what you mean when you say HeapByteBuffer is generated from a template" -- That simply means the majority of the Buffer subtypes don't actually exist as source files in the OpenJDK repository. They are generated from *.template files (see here) before compilation. And all the concrete implementations are package-private. But this is irrelevant to your question, other than saying that java.nio.HeapByteBuffer is both not directly accessible and is an implementation detail.

HeapByteBuffer is a subclass of ByteBuffer (and always was so since Java 1.4) and therefore your log statement should never execute. Maybe your actual problem is that while you extract a field from avro using Object recordValue = genericRecord.get(someField); you are actually processing some different value actualValue with unclear relationship to the extracted value.

As well as fixing use of actualValue vs recordValue, more logging such as log.warn("Unknown type "+actualValue+" cls="+actualValue.getClass()) might help.

The second example in my orignal answer works fine. Not sure what I did to hit the log.warn() before:
Object recordValue = genericRecord.get(someField);
switch (actualValue) {
   case String avroString -> {
      // do logic
   }
   case ByteBuffer avroBuffer -> {
      // do logic
   }
   default -> log.warn("Unknown type");
}


You haven't answered a key comment - which is, what error do you get? Because your original code (as in, the code in your question, not in this answer) works fine for everybody but you, apparently. What warning do you get? Possibly you have a linting tool or IDE that adds warnings and you've configured it to warn on silly things, or it's broken. We can't help unless you tell us what additional linters/compilers you are using; including the exact text of the warning might mean somebody knows which linter tool you've misconfigured.

@rzwitserloot I've edited the answer to make it more clear the warning i was referring to was the log.warn() line that gets called when recordValue is a HeapByteBuffer...

See my answer. You're not getting it. This workaround is useless.

You're operating under some serious misunderstandings. Here is a trivial example to show that your mental model of what is happening here is simply not correct:
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object i = Integer.valueOf(42);
        switch (i) {
            case Number n -> System.out.println("N: " + n.intValue());
            default -> System.out.println("NaN");
        }
    }
}

This prints N: 42.
In other words, your theory that you must name the precise, exact type that the thing is is simply not correct - you can stick a supertype in a case statement and it'll trigger just fine. Your 'workaround' of writing case Object i when i instanceof ByteBuffer is a silly way to write case ByteBuffer b.
If you are observing your default case triggering, then either [A] you are not compiling/running the code you think you are, or [B] HeapByteBuffer is not a ByteBuffer, and your case Object i when i instanceof ByteBuffer wouldn't work either, because it isn't a bytebuffer.
